# How choose from combobox, when is not type select

Tags: java, combobox, webdriver

I am creating an automatic test for some webs and I'm using WebDriver, TestNG and code that is written in Java and I need choose options 1 from combobox, but select element is not visible.

```
   Select element = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/form/fieldset/span/span[1]/span/span/select")));
   element.selectByValue("1");
```

html code for combobox is:

```
<span id="" class="selectboxit-container selectboxit-container" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" aria-owns="">
<span id="" class="selectboxit selectboxit-enabled selectboxit-btn selectboxit-open" name="c1" tabindex="0" unselectable="on" style="width: 157px;">
<span class="selectboxit-option-icon-container">
<i id="" class="selectboxit-option-icon selectboxit-container selectboxit-default-icon" unselectable="on"></i>
</span>
<span id="" class="selectboxit-text" unselectable="on" data-val="1" style="max-width: 81px;" aria-live="polite">Movité a ostatní</span>
<span id="" class="selectboxit-arrow-container" unselectable="on">
<i id="" class="selectboxit-arrow selectboxit-default-arrow" unselectable="on"></i>
</span>
</span>
<ul class="selectboxit-options selectboxit-list" tabindex="-1" style="min-width: 78.7667px; display: block; max-height: 62px; top: auto;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="selectboxit-option selectboxit-option-first" data-disabled="false" data-val="2" data-id="0" role="option">
<a class="selectboxit-option-anchor">
</li>
<li class="selectboxit-option selectboxit-option-last selectboxit-selected selectboxit-focus" data-disabled="false" data-val="1" data-id="1" role="option" data-active="">
</ul>
</span>
```

Can anyone advise me please? Thanks

URL link: http://www.labmultis.info/jpecka.portal-exdrazby/index.php

img: http://postimg.org/image/7o1eggfud/

Comment: Anyone has any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Its not Select element that is not dropdown to use Select command here.. I hope you can try by simulating click commands..

Thank You